# Unable to remove a special named files in terminal

Tags: rm

Some program makes ta my root directory dummy files such as

```
-1
-2
-3
...
-n
```

I run unsuccessfully

```
rm -1
```

and too

```
rm "-1"
```

Terminal thinks that -1 is the option.

**How can you remove the files** in terminal?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `rm ./-1`, the ./ refers to the current directory and as the parameter doesn't start with a dash it isn't interpreted as an option.

Comment: Yep, prepending ./ is indeed the classic solution to this problem.

Comment: this does not seem to work when using something like grep -i Content-Type.*pdf ./*.eml

Answer (score 5):

As far as I recall adding -- as an option on the commandline will cause the rm command to consider all the remaining arguments literally, so the command

```
rm -- -1
```

Will remove the funny named files. Note that you can still use shellextensions (such as '*' or '?') since the shell expand these *before* the command is run (unlike DOS).

*Edit*: When I was first faced with this problem, I didn't know about the -- switch so I wrote a small c program that would remove the file name the same as the first argument. This is easy to do since *all* posix operating systems contain the `unlink` system call which removes the file with the name given as argument (dump the following into a terminal):

```
remove_arg.c << EOF
#include<unistd.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv){
  unlink(argv[1]);
}
EOF
gcc -o remove_arg remove_arg.c
./remove_arg -1
```

This should work on any unix system, although you may have to change `gcc` into `cc` or what you local c compiler is named.

Comment: This will work with a GNU and a BSD userland, however it might *not* work with a Solaris or AIX userland. The ./-1 solution is more portable. Upvoted both.