# Delete a file in linux that contains double dash

Tags: linux, rm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unable to remove a special named files in terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/791155/unable-to-remove-a-special-named-files-in-terminal)

I feel silly asking, but how can I delete a file in linux named `--preserve-permissions`?

I tried:

```
rm "--preserve-permissions"

and

rm "\-\-preserve-permissions"
```

Neither works. Thanks.

Comment: One, two or more dashes, what's the difference? none, I believe.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There are several techniques, but the most straightforward for this kind of filename is:

```
rm ./--preserve-permissions
```

For filenames with unprintable or hard-to-decipher characters, use

```
rm -i *
```

This prompts with each filename and waits for a `y` or `n` whether to delete the file (interactive).

Comment: This is the most simple and powerful approach!

Answer (score 13):

Use:

```
rm -- --preserve-permissions
```

The `--` by itself means "switches end here, everything that follows is a file name".

Answer (score 2):

You can use inode number instead of the filename. See http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/delete-remove-files-with-inode-number.html

Comment: No, just give a path starting with `./` or with `/`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch this is the most generic method which gets you out of jam with any kind of weird filenames.

Comment: But you don't need that. The other answers are much more relevant.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch it solves the problem anyway

Comment: But the statement "you need to use inode number" is false; the original poster don't need to care about inode numbers, and the other replies are relevant even on file systems without reliable inode numbers (e.g. VFAT)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch fair enough, changed to can.